# Retrieving data from a database over the Internet on Android

Tags: php, android, database

I'm new when it comes to external **databases** (as I call it). I have a custom made [IPTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTV) app for own use. I add new channels very frequently, and I need each time to make a new release. I thought of a smarter way which is to **retrieve data from a database somewhere on the Internet**. So I can only update the database and avoid making releases so often.

As I know and have been reading, I need a **database**. I chose hostinger.se free databases. And I need a **PHP script**. I have almost zero knowledge in PHP. I need then to implement the method to read strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a server (e.g. with a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) API) then you need a PHP script. But if your database server is available over the Internet then you can just connect to it as well as to local.

But you need a driver for your database. As a rule, database vendors provide these drivers for different technologies.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to getting data into mobile devices then you need web services

So you should to create an **SQL** table containing your data (channels or whatever) and create a script that dump all that data into a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format and manipulate the response in your app.